# A class field as a function pointer in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, function-pointers, first-class

I want to have a function pointer in my class Point.

```
class Point:
  coord=[]

  def value(self,p_coord:list=coord):
    return abs(self.val(p_coord))

  def __init__(self,p_coord:list,p_val):
    self.coord=p_coord
    self.val=p_val
```

I'm trying to pass a function pointer to the field "val", But when I try to call the function with the method value(), it returns 0:

```
def length(par:list):
  return len(par)

v1=Point([1, 2, 3],length)
print(v1.value())
```

How to pass a function to a class field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value `coord` in `value` is the class attribute from line 2 which is not the same as the instance attribute `self.coord` set in `__init__`. So the function pointer is working correctly, its just looking at the wrong list.

What you can instead do is:

```
def value(self, p_coord=None):
    if not p_coord:
        p_coord = self.coord
    return abs(self.val(p_coord))
```